# Flutter set initial input value for Rive animation

Tags: flutter, dart, rive

I have a `rive` animation in my Flutter app and I would like to set the initial value for an `input`, so I can control at which point the animation starts. But I can't get it done.

This is what I've got:

```
  context.rive.dataBalloonsRIV.copyWith(
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
    onInit: (artboard) async {
      _controller = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
        artboard,
        _stateMachine,
      );

      if (_controller != null) {
        artboard.addController(_controller!);
        _amountInput = _controller!.findInput<double>('state');
        final startInput = _controller!.findInput<bool>('start');

        _amountInput?.value = 3;
        startInput?.value = true;
      }
      setState(
        () => (),
      );
    },
  ),
```

With this the animation will animate from start to inputValue 3.

I found [this](https://help.rive.app/runtimes/overview/react/parameters-and-return-values)  on the official rive docs, where an `initialValue` can be set. This sounds exactly like what I need, but I can't find a way to implement this in Flutter.

Is this possible? Has anyone done this before? Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, it is.

I have also struggled with this some time ago.

In my case, I have this method in my class to get the Rive Animation as a Widget:

```
Widget getWidget(double width) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: width,
    height: width,
    child: RiveAnimation.asset(
      "assets/rive/courses/$_fileName",
      controllers: [_controller],
      animations: [_animationName],
      artboard: _artboardName,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      stateMachines: [_stateMachineName],
      onInit: _onRiveInit,
    ),
  );
}
```

The "onInit:" points to my void function:

```
void _onRiveInit(Artboard artboard) {
  _stateMachineController = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, _stateMachineName)!;
  _addSMINumberToController(riveNumber);
  artboard.addController(_stateMachineController);
}
```

The "_addSMINumberToController" does, what I assume you need.

```
void _addSMINumberToController(RiveNumber num) {
  num.number = _stateMachineController.findInput<double>(num.location) as SMINumber;
  num.number!.change(num.value);
}
```

Note that the "RiveNumber" class is custom, and you can figure your own way out of it. My class looks like this:

```
class RiveNumber {
  SMINumber? number;
  String location;
  double value;
  RiveNumber({this.number, required this.location, required this.value});
}
```

Comment: Hi Frederik, thanks for your answer but I don't quite get what youre doing differently. I am also getting my input via `findInput` and change it with `.change`. But thats not doing it for me. I could send you the animation but I simply can not make it work :(

Comment: I do not know how or if Stack Overflow is okay with this means of transferring files, but maybe you can share the rive file with a link, and I will check if it works with my code.

Comment: that would be super helpful!

her you go: https://gofile.io/d/wwtjbJ

You can see all the neccessary inputs in the code above. It `state` (double) and `start` (bool)

Comment: It would be better with a .rev file, so I can check there too. I am missing the name of the artboard, so I cannot get it working.

Comment: its "State Machine 1"

Comment: here is the `rev` :) https://gofile.io/d/xDQiyB

Comment: "State Machine 1" is the State Machine Name, the artboard is called Datenreise. I can get it to show and animate, but what specifically is the problem?

Comment: I see, that you put in a boolean input for "start", but "start" in your .riv/.rev file is set as a trigger. So, the problem probably is there. If I did not misunderstand it, then you have to find a solution, where you use the boolean for it or trigger it with a tap in the rive file through an event. 

PS. The animations are pretty cool!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256979/discussion-between-chris-and-frederik-behrens).